# What percentage of users opt out of Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, adblock

You can block Google Analytics through Adblock or your hosts file, and I know a small amount of visitors do.  What's the percentage?  Does Google compensate somehow, or should I just add a fudge factor to my customer's stats.

I understand this number is possibly tiny, but I can't seem to dodge this request.

Comment: You can find out by working around the adblock, adding an exception or a custom variable. http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html

Answer (score 2):

If you site is getting any decent amount of traffic at all, this percent will be too small to worry about. I usually just ignore it.